# AMPL minimizing the sum of integers in a set and number of chosen elements

Tags: mathematical-optimization, ampl

Previously, I posted a question where I asked about how to select a minimum number of Integers from a set, and having a sum >= a constant.
My code was as shown:

```
option solver cplex;
set x:= {4, 5, 7, 1};
param c:= 10;
var u{x} binary;
minimize output : sum {i in x} u[i];
subject to constraint: sum {i in x} u[i]*i >= c;
solve;
display u;
```

I decided to add a new objective of minimizing the sum as well. 
In the previous example, cplex produces 12 (7 and 5). I want it to produce 11 (7 and 4).
For this purpose, I added this objective:

```
minimize output : sum {i in x} u[i]*i;
```

Unfortunately, I have a student edition of AMPL, so I cant use 2 objectives. Now my new code will solve the problem but I want to ask if there is a work around or a trick to combine the 2 objectives into 1 yet still having the same functionality.

EDIT: I'm more interested in minimizing number of elements then to minimize the sum.

Comment: In order to express that your question is solved, accept the answer that solved it. It can be your own answer.

Comment: Thanks ALi, I tried but a popup message appeared saying "I can accept my own Answer tomorrow". I'm waiting till tomorrow so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to solve my problem. I would like to share it with you guys.

```
option solver cplex;
set x:= {4, 5, 7, 1};                                                #this is the set where I want to chose the integers from.
param c:= 10;                                                        #this is the constant i want the sum to be >= to.
param MinNumberOfELements;                                           #this will be used later. Explanation will be added then.
var u{x} binary;                                                     #binary array, indicates the corresponding elements in x is used.  u[4] = 1 -->  4 is taken in the output
minimize output : sum {i in x} u[i];                                 #here we minimize number of taken elements without caring of minimizing the sum
subject to constraint: sum {i in x} u[i]*i >= c;                     # the sum must be >= to the constant c.
solve;                                                               #this will cause the objective "output" to have some value

let MinNumberOfELements := output;                                   # take the value of "output" and store it in this param.
drop output;                                                         #since we can have only 1 objective, we drop the old one.

minimize output2: sum {i in x} u[i]*i;                               # in this step, we minimize the sum
subject to constraint2: sum {i in x} u[i] = MinNumberOfELements;     #number of elements chosen must be = to MinNumberOfELements
solve;
display output2,u;
```

I hope you find it helpful.